# how can I check that there is at least 1 element in the path with a common title with the origin element (js arrays methods)?

Tags: javascript

how can I check that there is at least 1 element in the path with a common title with the origin element (js arrays methods)?

```
let origin = ['menu','info']

let path = [{title:'about'},{ title: 'menu' }]

let check = origin.some(el=>path.indexOf(el) !==-1) // true



let origin = ['menu','info']

let path = [{title:'about'},{ title: 'no-menu' }]

let check = origin.some(el=>path.indexOf(el) !==-1) // false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue with your code is that you are not checking the `title` property in the array of objects against your `origin` array.

On the other hand, it is also probably easier to invert the `Array.prototype.some` logic. In your original code, you are using `origin.some(...)`, which can be difficult because you will need to compare the string against a nested property in the `path` array. In the example below, using `path.some(p => origin.includes(p.title));` makes the comparison more straightfoward and simpler.

Also, since you're already using ES6, you can use `Array.prototype.includes` instead of `indexOf`.

See proof-of-concept below:

```js
let origin1 = ['menu','info']
let path1 = [{title:'about'},{ title: 'menu' }]
let check1 = path1.some(p => origin1.includes(p.title));
console.log(check1);  // Expect: true

let origin2 = ['menu','info']
let path2 = [{title:'about'},{ title: 'no-menu' }]
let check2 = path2.some(p => origin2.includes(p.title));
console.log(check2);  // Expect: false
```